# iOS Constraints of image view inside table view cell gets misplaced on scroll

Tags: ios, swift

The constraints for the image view inside Table view cell gets distorted on scroll.

The constraints are fine on initial load and view. Once the table view cell goes out of the view and we scroll back to get it, the image view gets displaced.

This is the screenshot of single TableViewCell. The globe icon is misplaced from its original spot (left of name and designation) and overlaps on the text below.
[image: Screenshot showing the misplaced image view]

Screenshot of prototype cell from storyboard
[image: Screenshot of cell from Storyboard]

The black lines show the constraints added on the storyboard.
Using XCode 8.0 with Swift 3.
I am doing something wrong with the constraints ?

Comment: I find it very hard to understand your sketches, maybe take a screenshot from ur storyboard?

Comment: @YuchenZhong I have updated the question to include screenshot from storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are missing a height constraint on the image view. Should be able to fix problem if you add that.

Also, maybe related as well, can you set your image view's content mode to aspect fit? Sometime like this:

ObjC

```
[self.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```

Swift

```
self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Comment: It didn't work. I set the constraint height=40 for imageView. Also set the contentMode to aspect fit.
It asked for changing vertical hugging priority for "details" to 252. I did. Updated the frames.
The problem still persists.!

Comment: I am not much knowledgeable with Auto Layouts. It didn't work initially. I changed added constraints to a new view controller and then deleted the constraints, added to previous view controller and then clean, then run. It got resolved. FYI, I do have height attribute + I have ">=" for the title as well.

Can you explain a little more about your answer why it was the case ?

Comment: I cannot really understand what you did with "changed added constraints to a new view controller and then deleted the constraints, added to previous view controller and then clean ... ". I was suggesting you to add the height constraint because it seems that you were missing it from the screenshot that you posted. Adding that should help, if it doesn't, hmm, I don't know ... Yay, constraints are a bit tricky to get them all right at the very beginning.

Comment: I think it is important to start with a small number of constraints, and gradually add more. And also it is important to understand every constraint when you add them, otherwise, it will just be a mess later on and a nightmare to debug.

Comment: Well, yes, I added the height constraint. It still didn't solve. So I tried cleaning and starting afresh with new view controller, prototype cell. That's what I mentioned above.
Anyway, it seemed to work. Thanks. Constraints are bit tricky, but I am starting to get a grasp of it.

Comment: Can you let me know why you mentioned that adding "height" would solve it ? Can you explain of how you arrived at this so that I can get to debug next time ?

Comment: Why I suggest you add a height is because, .. you don't have that. For images views, it would better to have one. Otherwise, if you think about it, the compiler cannot really tell how tall it is. After all, the height of the table is dynamic sometimes. So if you want to have a rule of thumb, always add a height and width constraints for image subviews inside a table view cell. And don't forget the set the `contentMode`.